# Panel Does not update TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a TreeView that is displayed inside a panel. The data in the TreeView is based on data returned from the database. The first time, the data is correct. The second time, the TreeView is not refreshed, and the previous data is still showing in the tree. I checked the list that contain the data. The list returned the correct data. I've Google the issue, and could not resolved it with some of the answers that were posted.  Here is a sample code of how the  TreeView is being created and added to the Panel.

```
    ReportGroups gr = new ReportGroups();
    var Name = gr.GetReportName(groupID);
    TreeView tr = new TreeView();
    tr.BeginUpdate();
    tr.Size = new Size(570, 600);
    tr.Name = "Home";
    tr.Nodes.Add("Reports Name");
    tr.CheckBoxes = true;
    if (Name.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Name)
        {
            if (item != null)
            {
                tr.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(item.reportName);
            }
        }
    }
    tr.Nodes[0].ExpandAll();
    tr.EndUpdate();
    this.pDisplayReportName.Width = tr.Width * 2;
    this.pDisplayReportName.Height = 300;
    this.pDisplayReportName.Controls.Add(tr);
    this.pDisplayReportName.Refresh();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hmm, just try this, this should be the last two line of your code  `this.pDisplayReportName.Refresh(); this.pDisplayReportName.Clear();  `

Comment: Since you do not post your full code, i dont know if its on your `onLoad` of `form event`. so if you addthe code and nothing show on your treeview. Try to call the `this.pDisplayReportName.Clear();` on your `LoadForm` event

Comment: @niang I added the this.pDisplayReportName.Clear(), and it fixed the issue. I was asking you to post your comment as an answer instead, so I can mark the question as Answer.

Comment: haha ok. answer posted now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `this.pDisplayReportName.Clear();` so data will not double up. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easy option would be to use `this.pDisplayReportName.Controls.Clear();` just after `tr.EndUpdate();`. But, this would cause an issue if you have other controls within the same Panel.

The best option would be to use `this.pDisplayReportName.Controls.RemoveByKey("MyTree");` instead of `this.pDisplayReportName.Controls.Clear();`

And, another option would be to add a TreeView in design time (with name `tr`) rather than dynamically to the panel. Then, use `tr.Nodes.Clear();` before `tr.BeginUpdate();` and remove following two lines from your code.

```
TreeView tr = new TreeView();
.
.
.
this.pDisplayReportName.Controls.Add(tr);
```

Cheers